# Getting Flags From a Network Interface

Tags: networking, go

Looking at the net/interface.go code it seems like the only way to get interface flags is as strings. Is this true?

```
if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "broadcast") {
```

Feels gross.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`net.Interface.Flags`](https://godoc.org/net#Interface) is a bitmask. To see if an interface has a certain flag, use the [bitwise AND operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) (`&`). For example:

```
if i.Flags&net.FlagBroadcast != 0 {
    // interface has broadcast
}
```